# Nothing Shown from widgets after creating a new project on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

After I install a new windows version, I download the latest update from Android studio 3.1.3. I was working in the past with old versions.
I start creating a new project and I found a strange problem is when the empty project starts by default I found a text view contains "Hello world" but the problem is that I do not see it on the layout even after I add a new button for example or any other one nothing showed on the layout see the image here
[image]

when I add a new button or other widgets I got this 
[image]
when I start a search on the problem, I found a solution to the constraints a layout problem, which is in the second screenshot, but I did not find a solution that nothing is shown from the widgets I already add like the button and the hello world text view. all the video that solve the constraints layout problem shows that the layout shown normally. and can be dragged without a problem but in my situation, nothing is shown I add many widgets and still the same problem.
**the rendering problem I got said**
Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.   Tip: Try to refresh the layout.
I refresh the layout and nothing happened
last thing I search on it I found that I should make some changes to my build. gradle file maybe, so I can see the widgets on the android view in the android studio again this my current build. gradle I don't know if I should change something.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.deathcap.secondproject"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

this an image after i run the application it show that it appeare in the emulator but not in the android studio itself 
[image]

Comment: Try to change ConstraintLayout  to RelativeLayout or LinearLayout if that fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding the Base. in the styles.xml file in the res/values/styles.xml
add the Base to this line

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```